Can call Patreon API from Postman but not Cloudflare worker
I’m trying to call the Patreon API from my Cloudflare worker.
Here’s my code block:
const url = `https://www.patreon.com/api/oauth2/v2/identity`;
const responseTest = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${c.env.PATREON_CREATORS_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.39.0',
        Accept: '*/*',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
    },
});

I copied the headers over from Postman, where the request works. The above request works as well, but it requires this entry in the headers 'User-Agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.39.0' which feels wrong to me.
Without that entry in the headers, I receive 403 Forbidden error.
Can someone help me understand why this is necessary and what I could replace it with so that my app works? What am I doing wrong here?

Maybe you just need any User-Agent entry, no matter what?

Thanks @UweKeim that was it. Not mentioned anywhere in the docs though and it started happening all of a sudden on an already working fetch request! I just used a dummy string as the value.
